# Dual axes for y with Altair

Tags: python, plot, axes, altair

I'm trying to create an interactive plot with dual axes. For example, I want to use two axes for `y1` and `y2` as they have different magnitude:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
source = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100, 1), 0).round(2),
                    columns=['A'], index=pd.RangeIndex(100, name='x'))
source = source.reset_index().melt('x', var_name='category', value_name='y1')
source['Type'] = 'First'

source_1 = source.copy()
source_1['y1'] = source_1['y1'] + 5
source_1['Type'] = 'Second'

source_2 = source.copy()
source_2['y1'] = source_2['y1'] - 5
source_2['Type'] = 'Third'

source = pd.concat([source, source_1, source_2])

source['y2'] = source['y1']/10

def singleY_chart(y):

    input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
    selection = alt.selection_single(name='Select', fields=['Type'],
                                       bind=input_dropdown)

    # Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
    nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                            fields=['x'], empty='none')

    # The basic line
    base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
        alt.X('x:Q'),
        alt.Y(y, type='quantitative')
    ).transform_filter(selection)

    # add drop-down menu
    line = base.mark_line().add_selection(selection)

    # Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
    # the x-value of the cursor
    selectors = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
        x='x:Q',
        opacity=alt.value(0),
    ).add_selection(
        nearest
    )

    # Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
    points = base.mark_point().encode(
        opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
    )

    # Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
    text = base.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
        text=alt.condition(nearest, alt.Y(y, type='quantitative'), alt.value(' '))
    )

    # Draw a rule at the location of the selection
    rules = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='gray').encode(
        x='x:Q',
    ).transform_filter(
        nearest
    )

    # Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
    chart = alt.layer(
        line, selectors, points, rules, text
    ).properties(
        width=500, height=300
    ).configure_axisX(
        labelAngle=0
    ).configure_axis(
        titleFontSize=12.5,
        labelFontSize=12.5
    ).configure_legend(
        titleFontSize=12.5,
        labelFontSize=12.5
    )

    return chart


singleY_chart('y1') 
# singleY_chart('y2')
```

The code above works for `y1` or `y2` separately. Now I want to plot `y1` on the left y-axis and `y2` on the right y-axis in the same plot, while being able to show the values of `y1` and `y2` the same time when I move my mouse on the plot. I searched online and found I might need to use `resolve_scale()` but I cannot figure out how I should use that.

EDIT:
I tried the following code:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
source = pd.DataFrame(np.cumsum(np.random.randn(100, 1), 0).round(2),
                    columns=['A'], index=pd.RangeIndex(100, name='x'))
source = source.reset_index().melt('x', var_name='category', value_name='y1')
source['Type'] = 'First'

source_1 = source.copy()
source_1['y1'] = source_1['y1'] + 5
source_1['Type'] = 'Second'

source_2 = source.copy()
source_2['y1'] = source_2['y1'] - 5
source_2['Type'] = 'Third'

source = pd.concat([source, source_1, source_2])

source['y2'] = source['y1']/10 + np.random.randn(300, )/10

def singleY_chart():

    input_dropdown = alt.binding_select(options=['First', 'Second', 'Third'])
    selection = alt.selection_single(name='Select', fields=['Type'],
                                       bind=input_dropdown)

    # Create a selection that chooses the nearest point & selects based on x-value
    nearest = alt.selection(type='single', nearest=True, on='mouseover',
                            fields=['x'], empty='none')

    # The basic line
    base = alt.Chart(source).encode(
        alt.X('x:Q')
    ).transform_filter(selection)

    # add drop-down menu
    line_1 = base.mark_line().encode(alt.Y('y1'),
                              color=alt.value('red')).add_selection(selection)

    line_2 = base.mark_line().encode(alt.Y('y2'),
                              color=alt.value('blue'))

    # Transparent selectors across the chart. This is what tells us
    # the x-value of the cursor
    selectors = alt.Chart(source).mark_point().encode(
        x='x:Q',
        opacity=alt.value(0),
    ).add_selection(
        nearest
    )

    # Draw points on the line, and highlight based on selection
    points = base.mark_point().encode(
        opacity=alt.condition(nearest, alt.value(1), alt.value(0))
    )

    # Draw text labels near the points, and highlight based on selection
    text = base.mark_text(align='left', dx=5, dy=-5).encode(
        text=alt.condition(nearest, alt.Y('y2:Q'), alt.value(' '))
    )

    # Draw a rule at the location of the selection
    rules = alt.Chart(source).mark_rule(color='gray').encode(
        x='x:Q',
    ).transform_filter(
        nearest
    )

    # Put the five layers into a chart and bind the data
    chart = alt.layer(
        line_1, line_2, selectors, points, rules, text 
    ).resolve_scale(
    y='independent'
    ).properties(
        width=500, height=300
    ).configure_axisX(
        labelAngle=0
    ).configure_axis(
        titleFontSize=12.5,
        labelFontSize=12.5
    ).configure_legend(
        titleFontSize=12.5,
        labelFontSize=12.5
    )

    return chart


singleY_chart()
```

This works to some extent but I have the following problems:

1. since only `x` is selected in the `base` the interactive plot only shows points on the x-axis instead of on the lines;
2. only the y-value of one line (other than both) is shown as specified in the `points()` and `text`;
3. How can I create legends for the two lines?

I'm thinking about melting the `y1` and `y2` into one column. Will that make it easier to do what I want?

Comment: It's not very clear from your question what the intended result is. The code is quite complicated and leads to an error when executed. Most uses of the word "interactive" within Altair and its documentation refer to panning and zooming. Are you trying to add panning and zooming to a dual-axis chat? You might read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and try to rephrase your question in a way that makes it more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Sorry - I probably misused the word 'interactive'. All I want to do is to plot `y1` in the left y-axis and `y2` in the right y-axis in the same plot while being able to show their values when moving the mouse across the plot. In addition I want to show the legends for `y1` and `y2`. Please let me know if I stated my problem clearly/

Answer (score 4):

I believe [resolve_scale](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/toplevel/altair.Chart.html#altair.Chart.resolve_scale) is what you need.

Put your chart in "()" and then `.resolve_scale(y='independent')` as in [this example from the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/layered_chart_with_dual_axis.html).

Comment: example here https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/scale_resolve.html